# findAll method Mongo Repository - exclude fields to build lighter objects

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, mongodb-query, mongorepository

I am using Spring Boot. I want to implemented findAll(boolean collapsed) method on my service. I am using MongoRepository as dao, and I wanted to use findAll method. If this collapsed parameter is set to false, then I
     **return dao.findAll(),**
but if collapsed is set to true, I wanted to exclude some heavy fields (like list). Can I exclude this fields with queries and using a constructor of my class which has less input parameters? I am new to querying with MongoRepository.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if using MongoRepository you can restrict the fields (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.3.3.RELEASE/reference/html/mongo.repositories.html)

```
@Query(value="{ 'firstname' : ?0 }", fields="{ 'firstname' : 1, 'lastname' : 1}")
List<Person> findByThePersonsFirstname(String firstname);
```

If you want to return different fields based on the parameter you can define 2 different methods in the MongoRepository interface